# Search suggestions strategy

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

Using Elasticsearch, Nutch and AngularJs to build a small search app and trying to choose a good search suggestion strategy to start. I've been using ES's `edge_n_grams` on the `HTML` `title` and `content`(body per nutch) which does an ok job. I've recently come across ES's completion suggester and would like to know if that may do a better job of creating multi-word (or single word) suggestions? Does anyone have any experience with ES Completion Suggester? Is it better or worse than using `edge_n_grams`? Any suggestions (no pun intended) are great.

Comment: Here is a good article that presents both approaches and helps you decide which one is the most appropriate for you: http://techblog.realestate.com.au/implementing-autosuggest-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: @Val, thanks for the link, your right, great article on suggestion strategy for ES